# Eclipse JDT autoformatting: indented statement after 'if' without braces

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting

I'm trying to set up Eclipse's autoformatting to conform to my company's coding style, but I'm having serious trouble with this situation: an 'if' statement has a single statement (not a block) which is a 'try' statement.  Our guidelines are that it should be formatted like this:

```
if (condition)
    try
    {
        something;
    }
    catch (WhateverException e)
    {
        and do something with it;
    }
```

but Eclipse seems to always want to format it like this:

```
if (condition) try
{
    something;
}
catch (WhateverException e)
{
    and do something with it;
}
```

I've looked through all the settings, and can't see anything that seems to do what I want, at least not without also preventing single-line if statements when they have simple content (which we do want).  Is there something I've missed, or can Eclipse not cope with this?

Comment: Is there a worldwide shortage of braces?

Comment: I have little sway over the coding style, unfortunately, it having been set by the company's founder.